# Angular 5 app not working in Microsoft Edge 40

Tags: javascript, angular, internet-explorer, angular-material, microsoft-edge

[image][image]I have angular 5.2 application. its working fine in chrome,firefox. but in Microsoft Edge 40.15063 its not loaded fully. we are using angular material design with scss. i enabled all IE/Edge support in pollyfills. but whenever i use microsoft edge i throws lot of error in debugging panel.

```
/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';

/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for NgClass support on SVG elements */
import 'classlist.js';  // Run `npm install --save classlist.js`.

/** Evergreen browsers require these. **/
import 'core-js/es6/reflect';
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';
import 'core-js/es7/array';


/**
 * Required to support Web Animations `@angular/animation`.
 * Needed for: All but Chrome, Firefox and Opera. http://caniuse.com/#feat=web-animation`enter code here`
 **/
import 'web-animations-js';  // Run `npm install --save web-animations-js`.

/*******************************************************************************
 * Zone JS is required by Angular itse`enter code here`lf.
 */
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';  // Included with Angular CLI.
```

do you anyone faced this issue ? please help me to resolve.i attached screenshot.may be its edge issue or angular issue. i dont know how to find ? i put lot of efforts to identify the issue. but all the time i was failed. here with i attached package.json & tsconfig.json

package.json

```
{
  "name": "sample",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve -o",
    "build": "ng build --prod --aot",
    "test": "ng test --watch=false",
    "testserve": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint --type-check",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "clearCache": "npm cache clean --force",
    "clearNodeModules": "rm -rf node_modules && npm run clearCache"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-mdl/core": "4.0.8",
    "@angular-mdl/popover": "0.10.0",
    "@angular-mdl/select": "0.13.0",
    "@angular/animations": "5.2.4",
    "@angular/cdk": "5.2.1",
    "@angular/common": "5.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "5.2.4",
    "@angular/forms": "5.2.4",
    "@angular/http": "5.2.4",
    "@angular/material": "5.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-server": "5.2.4",
    "@angular/router": "5.2.4",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "9.1.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "2.0.1",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "2.5.3",
    "diacritics": "1.3.0",
    "intl": "^1.2.5",
    "jquery": "1.9.1",
    "json-merge": "1.2.0",
    "jspdf": "1.4.1",
    "lodash": "4.17.5",
    "material-design-lite": "1.3.0",
    "moment-es6": "1.0.0",
    "popper.js": "1.13.0",
    "rxjs": "5.5.6",
    "shelljs": "0.7.8",
    "web-animations-js": "2.3.1",
    "write-json": "2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.20"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.7.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "5.2.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.2",
    "@types/jspdf": "1.1.31",
    "@types/node": "6.0.101",
    "codelyzer": "4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.1.0",
    "karma": "1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "1.4.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "0.2.2",
    "node-sass": "4.9.0",
    "protractor": "5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "3.0.4",
    "tslint": "5.3.2",
    "typescript": "2.6.2"
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es6",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: what error logs do you see in edge? edit your question and put it there.

Comment: its throws lot of errors. now i attached image

Comment: do you have a updated browser? try to clear cache and uninstall extensions. Can you try to open it in another windows profile?

Comment: @karoluS.  i did not installed any extension . and also how to open in another window profile ?

Comment: in edge error logs i see some errors about your browser extensions. disable or remove extensions and try again. also i see another error which is not clear, expand it: ERROR CONTEXT [object Object]

Comment: @Fartab, edge dont have any extension installed. and also  attached the expansion of ERROR CONTEXT [object Object]

Answer (score 0):

thanks guys who supported me. i like to answer my question.

i found the issue as 'Permission denied for accessing localstorage in Edge'. this may be happen in some workplaces for security reason.i solved the issue like below way

ininnerStorage = {};

```
public get(key: string): string {   

    try{
        return localStorage.getItem(key); 
    }
    catch(e){
        return this.innerStorage[key];
    }


}

public set(key: string, value: any): void {

    try{
        localStorage.setItem(key, value);
    }
    catch(e){
         this.innerStorage[key] = value
    }
}

public remove(key: string): void {  

    try{
        localStorage.removeItem(key);
    }
    catch(e){
         delete this.innerStorage[key]
    }

}
```

so i updated my code to use innerstorage if app not able to access localstorage

Comment: Can you provide a link to the issue which you found? I have the same problem and I want to find a reason.