# How to find source of error in Edge for Angular 7 app?

Tags: angular, microsoft-edge

I have an Angular 7 app that works as-designed in Firefox and Chrome. It mostly-works in Edge, except we noticed that this button toolbar doesn't appear for some reason. There is nothing special about the button toolbar, and it's even being rendered in the HTML (as far as I can trace), but when it gets to the part where the details of the template are supposed to be inserted, they are gone.

In any case, I see an error in the browser console. However, the error is non-specific and appears to be going through the compiled source. How do I back this out to see what is causing heartburn for Edge?

For reference, this is the error I get (I know it is not useful, but that's my question - how to get a useful error?)

> **Function code (1099) (5,3)**
>
> **[object Error]:** {description: "SyntaxError", message: "SyntaxError", ngDebugContext: Object, ngErrorLogger: function() { [native code] }, stack: "Error: SyntaxError at callWithDebugContext (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:83113:9) at debugCheckAndUpdateView (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:82805:5) at ViewRef_.prototype.detectChanges (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:80614:13) at Anonymous function (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:77045:51) at Array.prototype.forEach (native code) at ApplicationRef.prototype.tick (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:77045:13) at Anonymous function (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:76936:99) at ZoneDelegate.prototype.invoke (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2735:13) at onInvoke (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:76225:17) at ZoneDelegate.prototype.invoke (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2735:13)"}
>
> **[object Object]:** {component: Object, componentRenderElement: Object, context: Object, elDef: Object, elOrCompView: Object...}

Selected section of Angular.json:

```
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
            }
          ],
          "optimization": true,
          "outputHashing": "all",
          "sourceMap": false,
          "extractCss": true,
          "namedChunks": false,
          "aot": true,
          "extractLicenses": true,
          "vendorChunk": false,
          "buildOptimizer": true,
          "budgets": [
            {
              "type": "initial",
              "maximumWarning": "2mb",
              "maximumError": "5mb"
            }
          ]
        },
        "mock": {
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.mock.ts"
            }
          ]
        },
        "live": {
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.live.ts"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43557090/angularcli-disable-minification try this to see meaningful error

Comment: We are not running a prod build. This is dev server.

Comment: can you post your angular.json file too ?

Comment: Would there be something in the file you are looking for? I'd rather not post a big wall of file if a specific section or section(s) is more helpful.

Comment: `architect > build >configurations`

Comment: There ya go - question updated

Comment: I find some similar threads, the issue is related to localstorage in Edge. Some Libraray of Javascript or Brower which your Microsoft Edge doesn't support will cause problems. Have you used something like this in your app? You can refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52256562/angular-5-app-not-working-in-microsoft-edge-40) and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47988026/angular2-app-is-not-working-on-microsoft-edge).